# Расстановка запятых в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: спп, пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "за":

Ходил в сложные туристические походы(,) за которые и получил разряд по туризму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Предложение сложное, сложноподчиненное (есть союзное слово "за которые"), оба предложения односоставные.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Где же Вы видите односоставные предложения?

Comment: Поддерживаю Лорану. Это не односоставные, а неполные предложения.